# Spring form validation using annotation and @Valid

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am having some issues with my form validation.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = REGISTER_URL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerPost(@Valid RegisterForm registerForm,
                               BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return REGISTER_VIEW;
        }
        System.out.println(registerForm.getPassword());
        return LOGIN_VIEW;
    }
```

View:

```
<form:form action="register" commandName="registerForm" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username:</td>
                    <td><form:input path='username' /></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="username"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><form:password path='password'/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="password"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Repeat password:</td>
                    <td><form:password path='repeatedPassword'/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="repeatedPassword"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit">&nbsp;<input name="reset" type="reset"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
```

Form:

```
public class RegisterForm {

    @Size(min = 3, max = 15)
    private String username;

    @Size(min = 5)
    private String password;

    @Size(min = 5)
    private String repeatedPassword;

   // getters and setters omitted
}
```

When i enter empty values (username, password and repeatedPassword) then no errors occurs (i have checked it using debugger). So it looks like no validation is performed. Binding values from view is ok (checked using debugger) Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Add @NotEmpty annotation as well.

Comment: @StanislavL I did it and nothing. Anyway - when I enter some random characters (up to 4) nothing happens.

Comment: remove the action attribute from your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following content into your context:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="xxx.xxx.xxx" />
```

In the guide, they use `"@SpringBootApplication"`
http://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is equivalent to using `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` with their default attributes:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html

Comment: Thanks, <mvc:annotation-driven /> helped :)